# Duda sobre npm run build con vite y react

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

Estoy comenzando a desarrollar mis proyectos web son React y vite. Sin embargo, me di cuenta que el proyecto como tal pesa demasiado (más de 50mb).

Mi pregunta es ¿al correr el comando "npm run build" puedo borrar todos los otros archivos que me generó vite y quedarme solo con la carpeta "/dist" ?

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los otros archivos? No se como es con react, pero si lo que tenés es una carpeta "node_modules", lo que está ahí no es necesario para producción. Si, podrías borrarla y el proyecto debería funcionar. Pero si no tenés los archivos en esa carpeta, vas a tener que volver a instalar todo una y otra vez.
Lo que deberías hacer es simplemente NO publicar esa carpeta, no se como estás utilizando el proyecto.

Comment: Exacto, node_modules es la carpeta que pesa bastante.  Muchas gracias por la respuesta, hermano. Resolviste mi duda, no sabía si borrar node_modules afectaría mi proyecto en produccion.

Comment: Buenísimo, me alegro. Lo publique como respuesta para que quede resuelta la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La carpeta `node_modules` no es necesaria para producción, podés borrarla.
El tema es que para desarrollo si es necesaria y para poder volver a correr un `npm run build` vas a tener que volver a instalar todo `node_modules`.

En general lo que se hace es en un `.gitignore` ignorar la carpeta para que no se publique en tu repositorio.
Pero sin saber como estás utilizando tu proyecto más no te puedo ayudar.

Lo que si son importantes, y entiendo debés tener, son los archivos `package.json` y `package-lock.json`. Dichos archivos tienen el listado de paquetes a instalar y el último las versiones exactas que tenés instaladas.